# Django RedirectView and reverse() doesn't work together?

Tags: python, django

I'm having this weird problem.

When I did this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('account-reco-about-you')
# returns '/accounts/recommendations/about-you/'
```

But when I did this:

```
# Doesn't Work
recommendations = login_required(RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse('account-reco-about-you')))

# Work
recommendations = login_required(RedirectView.as_view(url='/accounts/recommendations/about-you'))
```

Error message I get if unrelated. It says my last view is not found, which is there. Any explanation? Meantime, i'll make do with the non-reverse style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem is to do with trying to reverse something at import time before the URLs are ready to be reversed. This is not a problem with RedirectView itself - it would happen with anything where you tried to reverse in your urls.py file, or possibly in a file imported by it.

In the development version of Django, there is a function called [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy) specifically to help in this situation.

If you're using an earlier version of Django, there is a solution here: [Reverse Django generic view, post_save_redirect; error 'included urlconf doesnt have any patterns'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794655/reverse-django-generic-view-post-save-redirect-error-included-urlconf-doesnt-h).

Answer (score 9):

You need to use "reverse_lazy" that is defined in "django.core.urlresolvers" in Django 1.4 and above.

Here is an example urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.website.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='website_home'),
    url(r'^redirect-home/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('website_home')), 
        name='redirect_home'),

)
```

So in the above example, the url "/redirect-home" will redirect to "/".  Hope this helps.

Comment: With Django 2.1 `from django.urls import reverse_lazy`

Answer (score 8):

no need for `reverse()` or `reverse_lazy()`.

simply specify the `pattern_name` parameter:

```
RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='account-reco-about-you')
```

Comment: `pattern_name` is available for v >= 1.6. However, in `urls.py` it doesn't seem to work for me... It returns 410 like when no url is specified.

Comment: Didn't help in django 1.11

Answer (score 3):

@wtower
`pattern_name` will be ok, but you may need to add namespace as below.

```
RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='polls:index')
```